# Azure AppService, Stack Settings resetting by itself, after upgrading to NET 8

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We recently upgraded a few app services to net8.0 and changed the stack configuration accordingly:

[image]

But from time to time (sometimes a few times a day, sometimes a few times a week) the app service stops working, and checking the configuration we find back .NET 7 instead of 8:

[image]

We simply change it back to .NET 8, the app service restarts automatically, and then it works.

Logs show no one changed the configuration manually. No pipeline was running at these times.

What the hell could it be?

Comment: How you have deployed your App?

Comment: @Harshitha DevOps pipeline AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4 with RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|8.0'

Comment: Do you have any deployment slot in place that is performed automatically during your pipeline?

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps Nope.

Comment: That's really weird, and I know isn't the answer you were looking for but raise a ticket with Microsoft, as this seems to be an odd behavior from App Service

I found a similar issue with old version, perhaps you could also have a look at your end https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/436954/azure-app-service-reverts-net-5-to-net-3-1-after-p

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps at the end we created a new AppService replacing the old one and the problem disappeared